# $f, \hat {f} \in L^{p} \cap L^{\infty} \implies f\in A(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

$1\leq p \leq \infty $.
We put, 
$$X_{p}= \{f\in L^{p}(\mathbb R)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R) :\hat{f}\in L^{p}(\mathbb R)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\};$$ and we consider the algebra of Fourier transforms(functions of Fourier transforms), namely, $$A(\mathbb R) =\{f:\mathbb  R \to \mathbb C : \exists \ g\in L^{1} (\mathbb R)   \   \text{such that } \  \hat{g}=f \}. $$

For $p=1,$ clearly, by inversion formula, $X_{p} \subset A(\mathbb R).$

> **My Question**: Can we expect, $X_{p} \subset A(\mathbb R)$; for $1<p \leq \infty$?  At least for some values of $p$; Or we get a counter example for some values of $p$ ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We will answer negatively to this question. Note that the elements in $A(\Bbb{R})$ are all uniformly continuous functions. So, to find a counter example, we only need to consider some discontinuous function $f$.

Let $f(x)={\bf 1}_{[-1,1]}(x)$ then it is easy to see that $f\in X_p$ for every $p\in(1,+\infty]$ but $f\notin A(R)$. So $X_p\not\subset A(\Bbb{R})$ for every $1<p<+\infty$.

Comment: @OK; thanks; but sorry I could not follow you how did you conclude $\hat{f} \in L^{1}$ ; see, Holders inequality, tells us, $\|fg\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \leq \|f\|_{L^{p}} \cdot \|g\|_{L^{q}}$; so if I take $f$ and $g$ both as $\hat{f}$, then I get $\hat{f} \in L^{2}$ and not in $L^{1}$; or am I missing something completely; thanks a lot;

Comment: @ prof. OK; would you please tell me, I am keen to know, how  you are getting, $\hat{f} \in L^{1}$ if $\hat{f} \in L^{p}\cap L^{q}$; ? thanks a lot;

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I corrected my answer.